# MAUI issue with clr-namespace

Tags: maui

I created separate folder Administration in Pages, however, the following error is showing up:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:ODDMob.Pages:AdminPage".
```

In AppShell.xaml I have the following:

```
    <Shell
        x:Class="ODDMob.AppShell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ODDMob.Pages"
        xmlns:administration="clr-namespace:ODDMob.Pages.Administration"
    ....
    
        <TabBar x:Name="MyTabBar" Title="Binding Current Title">
            <Tab>
            <ShellContent x:Name="TabStatisticsPage"  Icon="statistics.svg" Title="Statistics" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:StatisticsPage}" Route="StatisticsPage" IsVisible="False"/>
        </Tab>

            <Tab>
                <ShellContent x:Name="AdminPage"  Icon="secureshield.svg" Title="Administrator" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AdminPage}" Route="AdminPage" IsVisible="False"/>
            </Tab>
            
        </TabBar>
    
    </Shell>
```

With the other tab 'TabStatisticsPage' I don't have any errors even if the page is located in a separate folder. I tried to Clean/Build several times to close the VS but nothing helped. I even rebooted the PC a few times.

This is the structure of Pages:
Administration->AdminPage.xaml

Partials(Its folder)-> few pages

Statistics(its folder)-> few pages

...rest of the pages

I add the AdminPage into Partials but still, it doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ODDMob.Pages.Partials.AdminPage"
             Title="AdminPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="AdminPage to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: folder structure and namespace structure are completely independent of each other.  Just because you place something in a subfolder does not automatically create a namspace (VS, I believe, has options to control this).  Check the actual `namespace` declaration in the source code

Comment: The namespace is correct. I deleted the folder and created another one but still the problem remains.

Comment: shouldn't this `local:AdminPage` be `administration:AdminPage`?

Comment: I tried that one too, maybe Administration is keyword ? :|

Comment: Please post AdminPage

Comment: .. and include it’s namespace declaration. (I know you said it’s correct, but this ensures we are all looking at the full code.)

Comment: Since it doesn’t complain about StatisticsPage, does that have a different namespace declaration?

Comment: You are right. StatisticsPage is located in the Main Pages folder, now I add another AdminPage in the Pages folder it doesn't seem to have any issues. Instead of local:AdminPage why it doesn't work subfolder like @Jason mention it?

Comment: the `xmlns` you are using in the AppShell needs to match the `xmlns` the page is actually in

Comment: You are absolutely right.  All I needed in ShellPage to add "   xmlns:Administration="clr-namespace:ODDMob.Pages.Administration" and the contentTemplate="{DataTemplate Administration:AdminPage}. I'm happy to solve this issue and learn something new. Thank you!

Comment: isn't that exactly what I suggested an hour ago?

Comment: I thought you refer to AdminPage.cs namespace, sorry.